# Printing a K-ary tree stored in level-order in an array

Tags: java, performance, array, tree, formatting

I am given an array that represents a k-ary tree (I am also given the branching factor "k") that is stored in level order. My task was to print the tree in level order.

For example a trinary tree stored as {0,1,2,3,null,null,null,7,8,9,10,11,12} (It doesn't have to be full or complete) would print out as:

```
0
1 2 3
null null null 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

My solution currently works fine but it is very messy and not as elegant as I would prefer. The runtime complexity is also very bad (I don't know if Math.pow is O(1) or O(n) but if it's O(1), my code is still O(n) which is not ideal. If Math.pow is O(n) then my code is O(n<sup>2</sup>) which is garbage.

Is there another approach I am not seeing or can my existing code be optimized at all?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int k = 3;
  Integer[] arrInt = {0,1,2,3,null,null,null,7,8,9,10,11,12};

  String ans = arrInt[0] + "\n";
  int currLvl = 1;
  int prevLvl = 0;
  //Print all values
  for(int i = 1; i < arrInt.length-1; ++i){
    //Add a line if we reach a new level
    if(i == (Math.pow(k, currLvl)+Math.pow(k, prevLvl))){
      currLvl++;
      prevLvl++;
      ans+= "\n";  
    }
    ans+= " " + arrInt[i];
  }
  //EDGE CASE TO HANDLE LAST ELEMENT
  ans+= " " + arrInt[arrInt.length-1];
  System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your biggest performance problem is the repeated string concatenation using the `+` operator.  Since Java strings are immutable, every `+=` operation requires allocating a new string and copying the previous contents.  Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

`Math.pow()` should be avoided, since it performs floating-point arithmetic, and this task should be accomplished using just integer arithmetic.  Why not keep track of the desired width of the current row, and use an inner loop to print each row?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 3;
    Integer[] arrInt = {0,1,2,3,null,null,null,7,8,9,10,11,12};

    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, width = 1; i < arrInt.length; i += width, width *= k) {
        for (int j = i, end = Math.min(i + width, arrInt.length); j < end; ++j) {
            ans.append((j > i) ? " " : (j > 0) ? "\n" : "")
               .append(arrInt[j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Comment: I considered doing this but that means I would be nesting a for loop so I would get O(n^2) complexity. In practice, this may not be that bad but I would prefer to keep it at O(n).

Comment: No, your analysis is too simplistic! Despite the nesting, it's still O(n), because it visits every element exactly once. Note that in the outer loop, the `i += width` means that `i` skips straight to the next row.

Comment: Ah I see! That was my mistake then. Yes that would be a much better approach if the complexity is still O(n).

Comment: I am a little confused though, what exactly is your ternary checking?  Is that a nested ternary?

Comment: Yes, it's a nested ternary that decides what kind of whitespace to insert. It's saying: in most cases, put a space before each entry, but if it's the first entry in a line, put a newline instead, and in the special case of the very first entry, no leading whitespace is needed at all. I could also have written `.append((j == 0) ? "" : (j == i) ? "\n" : " ")`, but that would be less efficient for the common case. (Your original code didn't have that conditional, and thus it puts a space at the beginning of the second and subsequent lines.)

Comment: Oh i get it now. And yeah I realized that the extra space was being added so I just added a space to the first index to compensate. Your solution is much better though. And one last thing, could you explain what the math.min is doing? I'm a bit confused by how you are finding that the iteration has reached the next level of the tree.

Comment: `Math.min()` says to proceed to the end of that row, but keeping in mind that the bottom row might be incomplete.

Comment: I see. That makes sense, and it handles the edge case well. Thank you so much